# How to transform events with an IO function?

Tags: haskell, frp, reactive-banana

Let's say I have

```
e1 :: Event t A
f  :: A -> IO B
```

I want to create

```
e2 :: Event t B
```

which is triggered by `e1`, and whose values are determined by executing `f` on the value of `e1` at the time of the event occurrence.

I see two potential ways to do this, via dynamic event switching and using handlers, but they both look too complicated for such a simple thing.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: is `unsafePerformIO` an option?

Comment: @Ankur: no, that is definitely not a «proper way».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function `f` has a side effect, this is actually not a simple thing to do. The main reason is that the order of side effects is not well-defined when there are multiple simultaneous events. More generally, I was unable to conceive a good semantics for dealing with IO actions in events. Consequently, reactive-banana does not provide a pure combinator for this situation.

If you want to do this anyway, you have to use a more elaborate mechanism that also determines the order of side effects. For instance, you can use `reactimate` and write a combinator

```
mapIO :: Frameworks t => (a -> IO b) -> Event t a -> Moment t (Event t b)
mapIO f e1 = do
    (e2, fire2) <- liftIO newAddHandler
    reactimate $ (\x -> f x >>= fire2) <$> e1
    fromAddHandler e2
```

However, note that this may give unexpected results as the result event `e2` is no longer simultaneous with the input event `e1`. For instance, behaviors may have changed and other side effects may have been executed.

Comment: It is a bit surprising, given that the whole purpose of FRP is to deal with IO, that IO actions are not "first-class".

In particular, simultaneous events do have ordering — so why not use the same ordering for the corresponding effects?

I understand that this is not bullet-proof — e.g. an IO action can possibly trigger other events, or take too much time to regard events as "simultaneous"... But I can take a responsibility for that; that is, I promise not to invoke any event handlers and the action will be "instantaneous" for my purposes. Is it still impossible? Why?

Comment: Well, simultaneous events may have an ordering in every event, but there is no global ordering. Consider the two events `union ex ey` and `union ey ex` where `ex` and `ey` have simultaneous occurrences. A program may happily use both combinations at the same time, but the order of simultaneous event occurrences will be different for each. More generally, I could not find a good semantics for ordering IO actions in events, hence reactive-banana does not support them. (I have updated my answer to emphasize this point.)

Comment: Concerning FRP in general, I hope this does not come as a disappointment, but the focus is on calculating with events and time-varying values and not so much on IO. That said, you often need to interface with IO at the boundary, and there are many possibilities: `reactimate`, or the `mapIO` combinator presented here, or the `mapIO` combinator in the `Reactive.Banana.Frameworks.AddHandler` module which can be used to modify events before passing them to the FRP world.

Comment: @HeinrichApfelmus, could you please give an example of how to use `mapIO` from `Reactive.Banana.Frameworks.AddHandler`? Or maybe you could point to a better solution: in wxHaskell `Selecting` fires non-parametric event, so in order to know what is actually selected, I intend to use such `mapIO` after the event occurrence.

Comment: @sukhmel Have a look at the [reactive-banana-wx source](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana/blob/master/reactive-banana-wx/src/Reactive/Banana/WX.hs#L99).

Answer (score 0):

Can you call function `f` in `reactimate` (which as far as I understand is the "proper way" to handle IO from the event network)? From there, fire a new event of type `Event t B` to the event network. Or is this what you meant by "using handlers"?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by "using handlers".